# jQuery loader gif and alert message

Tags: jquery, ajax, loader

I have a form, when I click on the save button I would like to display a gif loader, then execute a ajax function (from jquery) to call a file which will save the form, the if it's a success, I want to remove the gif loader and display a message to say the form was successfully saved.

It's not hard... except for me ;o)

Here my code in fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WnZ3Y/

```
$("button#Save").click(function(){                                     
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "",
        data: $('').serialize(),
        beforeSend : function() { // JS code processing before calling the AJAX method
            $('#ajaxLoader-inner').html('Here my loader GIF'); // add a gif loader  
        },
        success: function(){
            $('#ajaxLoader-inner').fadeOut('slow').delay(2000); // remove GIF loader
            $('#ajaxLoader-inner').html('<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable" id="ajax-loader-message"><i class="fa fa-check"></i><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>Saved with success.</div>').fadeIn('slow').delay(2000).fadeOut('slow'); // add a message to say it's a success
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("Error in ajax."); // alert there is an error
            $('#ajax-loader-inner').fadeOut(); // remove GIF loader
        }
    });
});
```

So I need some help, please, to find why it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you know Blockui? That will help you a lot. here the site http://malsup.com/jquery/block/

Comment: Lots of "I want" and no question. Please clarify. Any console errors? Your fiddle doesn't help much as it isn't set up to actually run.

Comment: it seems very interesting but i prefere to avoid to add another "plugin" to my code.

Comment: lot of "i want"??? just one time and "i would" ;o). My jsfiddle works, this is the result i have and i described in my first message the process i'm waiting about... as you can see in jsfiddle the result is not good: the first time you click the button, it seems to work, but the second time is a mess! So, there is no question, i just need help.

Comment: Notes: You have `#ajax-loader-inner` instead of `#ajaxLoader-inner` for the error case. You are not waiting for the fade out before replacing the content. `fadeOut` is asynchronous but `delay` only delays subsequent animations, not the html replacement (which happens before the `fadeOut` commences).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

html

```
<form id="ajaxLoader">
    <div id="ajaxLoader-inner"></div>
    <input id="inputs" name="saved" type="text" placeholder="save" />
    <input type="button" id="Save" value="click" />
</form>
```

js

```
   $(function () {
        $("#Save").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var _data = $("#ajaxLoader input[type=text]").val();
            return $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/echo/json/",
                data: {
                    json: JSON.stringify({"saved" : _data})
                },
                beforeSend: function () { // traitements JS à faire AVANT l'envoi
                    $('#ajaxLoader-inner')
                    .html('<img src=http://upload.wikimedia.org/'
                          + 'wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d3/'
                          + 'Newtons_cradle_animation_book_2.gif/'
                          + '200px-Newtons_cradle_animation_book_2.gif />'); // add a gif loader  
                },
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                    $('#ajaxLoader-inner img').fadeOut(5000, function () { // remove GIF loader
                        $(this)
                        .replaceWith('<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable"'
                        + ' id="ajax-loader-message">'
                        + '<i class="fa fa-check"></i>'
                        + '<button type="button" class="close"'
                        + ' data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×'
                        + '</button>Saved with success.</div>') 
                        && $(".alert").fadeIn(0).fadeOut(3700)
                           .parent().siblings("#inputs").val("");
                    }) // add a message to say it's a success
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Error in ajax."); // alert there is an error
                    $('#ajax-loader-inner').fadeOut(); // remove GIF loader
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/6tpT6/

Answer (score 0):

A few minor tweaks below. Not exactly sure what your overall aim is, but the following issues were noted:

Notes:

- You have `#ajax-loader-inner` instead of `#ajaxLoader-inner` for the error case.
- You are not waiting for the fade out before replacing the content. `fadeOut` is asynchronous but `delay` only delays *subsequent animations*, not the `html()` replacement (which happens before the `fadeOut` commences). I chained the delay using `done` on the animation `promise`, which will trigger when the animation queue ends (including `delay` calls). You might be better off with a simple `setTimeout` there.
- You need to fadeIn (or show) the initial loader, as it is hidden by previous saves/errors.

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/WnZ3Y/2/

```
$("button#Save").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "",
        data: $('').serialize(),
        beforeSend: function () { // traitements JS à faire AVANT l'envoi
            $('#ajaxLoader-inner').html('Here my loader GIF').fadeIn(); // add a gif loader  
        },
        success: function () {
            $('#ajaxLoader-inner').fadeOut('slow').delay(2000).promise().done(function () {
                $('#ajaxLoader-inner').html('<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable" id="ajax-loader-message"><i class="fa fa-check"></i><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>Saved with success.</div>').fadeIn('slow').delay(2000).fadeOut('slow'); // add a message to say it's a success
            });
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Error in ajax."); // alert there is an error
            $('#ajaxLoader-inner').fadeOut(); // remove GIF loader
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to show the "ajaxLoader-inner" DIV:

```
    beforeSend : function() { // traitements JS à faire AVANT l'envoi
        $('#ajaxLoader-inner').show();
        $('#ajaxLoader-inner').html('Here my loader GIF'); // add a gif loader  
    },
```